# Why Chrome web store manifest?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Whats wrong chrome doesn't allow to upload a zip file

An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

manifest.json:17:2: unexpected char.

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "TechnoSwift Launcher",
      "description": "Quick launch TechnoSwift",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "author":"Shareque",
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "TechnoSwift Launcher"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
      ],
    }
```

Comment: Could be the comma after the permissions array, it should probably not be there since there is no more field in the object.

Comment: The error message says line 17 but the manifest in question only has 15 lines. Show us the real manifest.json or adjust the error message accordingly, please.